# Catching an exception by value - gcc and clang disagree

Tags: c++, gcc, exception, clang, language-lawyer

Consider this short snippet:

```
struct B {
    B() = default;
    explicit B(B const& ) { }
};

struct D : B { };

int main() {
    try {
        throw D{};
    }
    catch(B ) {
    }
}
```

gcc accepts this code, clang considers it ill-formed with:

```
main.cpp:17:13: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'B'
    catch(B ) {
            ^
```

Who's right?

Comment: Also, maybe both are right..

Comment: @xaxxon I doubt something like this is unspecified. Either it's supposed to be valid or it's supposed to be invalid. Either way, exceptions are weird.

Comment: Hmm, GCC correctly rejects it if you try to throw a `B`, but not if you try to throw a `D`.

Answer (score 4):

I *think* this is a gcc bug (and since nobody has downvoted this answer yet, I submitted it as [70375](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70375)).

Both compilers correctly agree that `D{}` should be caught, as per [[except.handle]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.handle#3), which only checks that `B` is a base class of `D`.

But the initialization of the handler is defined in [[except.handle]/15](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.handle#15) as:

> The variable declared by the exception-declaration, of type *cv* `T` or *cv* `T&`, is initialized from the exception object, of type `E`, as follows:
>   — if `T` is a base class of `E`, the variable is copy-initialized (8.5) from the corresponding base class subobject of the exception object;

That implies that initialization works as:

```
D __temporary_object{};
B __handler = static_cast<B&>(__temporary_object);
```

which should be disallowed since `B`'s copy constructor is marked `explicit` (and copy-initialization just doesn't cut it).

Comment: and removing the "explicit" in your example makes clang accept the except.